Github actions not always being triggered on large push requests
I have a git repo that contains 7 different projects. Each project contains a unique github actions workflow file. this file is triggered when pushing to specific branches (production, development)
Our team has recently encountered an issue where on certain large commits to all 7 projects, only a couple of the workflows are being successful triggered. sometimes only 2 or 3 of 7 gets triggered. Even though I can see in the PR that changes are there and detected by github.
Any idea why this is happening?  All the workflow files are identical with the exception of the deployment channel/project names.  I am unable to personally re create the issue, and when myself or other users merge PR's it works fine. But I noticed that this issue only ever happens when a certain user initiates and merges the PR. It has happened 3 times now, and things are not being deployed properly unless myself or someone else re triggers the workflow. There are no error msgs, the workflow action simply does not run. I have verified its not a github status issue as I can retrigger the deployment within minutes when i notice the problem.
I am quite at a loss as the user in question has the same repo permissions as myself.
# websiteEn Stage area workflow Actions.
# Includes npm webpack minification process
# .net core build, publish, release & deploy prcocesses.


name: websiteEn Production Build-Deploy Action

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "Production" ]
    paths:
      - websiteEn/**  

jobs:      
  # is responsible for the css & js file optimzation strategy
  # uses webpacks and npm to extract css and js
  # and replaces the dist folder with all the resources
  # builds and uploads artifact with the contents for use in subsequent jobs
  job1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest    
    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [20.x]
    steps:
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
          node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}        
    - name: build webpack
      uses: actions/checkout@v1      
    - run: ls -a    
    - run: npm i
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/ClientApp    
    - run: npm run build    
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/ClientApp    
    - run: pwd
    - run: ls -a    
    - name: Persist npm build output
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
      with:
        name: npm-post-build
        path: | 
          websiteEn/websiteEn/wwwroot/dist/**
  # handles the .net core build, publish, package & deployments
  job2:
    needs: job1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest   
    outputs:
      octoReleaseNum : ${{ steps.octoRelease.outputs.release_number }}
    steps:    
    # require to package the published project to octopus deploy
    - name: Install Octopus Deploy CLI
      uses: OctopusDeploy/install-octopus-cli-action@v1
      with:
        version: '*'
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Setup .NET
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
      with:
        dotnet-version: 7.0.x
    - name: Restore dependencies
      run: dotnet restore
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/ 
    - name: loc check
      run: pwd
    - name: replace dist with npm build artifact
      uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
      with: 
        name: npm-post-build
        path: npm-post-build    
    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --no-restore   
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/
    - name: Publish
      run: |
        dotnet publish -p:PublishProfile=PublishProfile -o website -f=net7.0
        # replace the dist folder with artifact from job1
        # ensures non-devs will not need to worry about builds for optimization
        ls -a
        rm -r website/wwwroot/dist
        ls website/wwwroot
        mv /home/runner/work/websites/websites/npm-post-build website/wwwroot/dist
        ls website/wwwroot/dist
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/
    # Generates the final package which we send and deploy to and via octopus
    - name: package
      run: |
        pwd
        ls -a
        echo website dir
        ls -a website
        echo "Done Check begin comperession"
          shopt -s globstar
            paths=()
            for i in website/**; do
              dir=${i%/*}
              echo ${dir}
              paths=(${paths[@]} ${dir})
            done
            eval uniquepaths=($(printf "%s\n" "${paths[@]}" | sort -u))
            for i in "${uniquepaths[@]}"; do
              echo $i
            done        
            packages=()
            versions=()                      
            echo " running octo pack"            
            for path in "${uniquepaths[@]}"; do              
              if [[ "$path" != *"wwwroot/Downloads/"* ]]; then
                dir=${path}/../../..
                parentdir=$(builtin cd $dir; pwd)
                projectname=${parentdir##*/}          
                octo pack \
                --basePath ${path} \
                --id ${projectname} \
                --version 1.0.0 \
                --format zip \
                --overwrite
                packages=(${packages[@]} "${projectname}.1.0.0.zip")
                versions=(${versions[@]} "${projectname}:1.0.0")
              fi
            done
        
            printf -v joined "%s," "${packages[@]}"
            printf -v versionsjoinednewline "%s\n" "${versions[@]}"
            versionsjoinednewline="${versionsjoinednewline//'%'/'%25'}"
            versionsjoinednewline="${versionsjoinednewline//$'\n'/'%0A'}"
            versionsjoinednewline="${versionsjoinednewline//$'\r'/'%0D'}"            
            echo "prepackage complete ${packages}"
            mv websites.1.0.0.zip www.websiteEn.1.0.0.zip
      working-directory: websiteEn/websiteEn/
    # send the newly created package to our octopus library
    - name: Push a package to Octopus Deploy
      uses: OctopusDeploy/push-package-action@v3
      env:
            OCTOPUS_URL: https://website.octopus.app/
            OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ****
            OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'MarketingTest'
      with:
            overwrite_mode: OverwriteExisting
            packages:  websiteEn/websiteEn/www.websiteEn.1.0.0.zip                
    # Octopus Create Release 
    - name: Generate Octopus Release
      id: octoRelease
      uses: OctopusDeploy/create-release-action@v3      
      env:
        OCTOPUS_URL: https://website.octopus.app/
        OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ****
        OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'MarketingTest'
      with: 
          project: 'website Web'
          channel: 'www.websiteEn'
          package_version: 1.0.0
    - name: versionCheck
      run: echo ${{steps.octoRelease.outputs.release_number}}
      # Deployment
    - name: Deploy Octopus Tenanted Release
      id: octoDeploy    
      uses: OctopusDeploy/deploy-release-tenanted-action@v3
      env:
            OCTOPUS_URL: https://website.octopus.app/
            OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ****
            OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'MarketingTest'
      with: 
        project: 'website Web'
        release_number: ${{steps.octoRelease.outputs.release_number}}
        environment: 'Production'
        tenants: |
            website websites
    - name: Await task in Octopus Deploy 
      uses: OctopusDeploy/await-task-action@v3
      env:
          OCTOPUS_URL: https://website.octopus.app/
          OCTOPUS_API_KEY: ****
          OCTOPUS_SPACE: 'MarketingTest'
      with:
          server_task_id: ${{ fromJson(steps.octoDeploy.outputs.server_tasks)[0].servertaskid }}                     
            
    


By any chance, is the specific user this issue presents with working off a fork? Some Actions configs can be set to not run if a PR is coming from a fork.

no its all in our repo. Based on what i can tell its when PR's contain > 500 file changes
